# How to enable all special symbols in VS Code terminal? My current setup inclush item2 + ohmyzsh + powerlevel10k

Tags: visual-studio-code

[My current setup vs how it actually looks in vs code[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyUkA.png)

[vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoaDS.png)

Comment: See docs: https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#manual-font-installation.

Answer (score 4):

"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "MesloLGS NF"

Adding this in code > user > settings.json helped.

source: https://gist.github.com/480/3b41f449686a089f34edb45d00672f28